# Calculating Gas Fees

Tags: hardhat, fees

I'm trying to build a test (hardhat) on the withdrawal of a smart contracts funds and then making sure that the funds received are the correct amount.

I've spent ages trying to figure out what i am missing but the amounts received are slightly out.

Here is my code so far:

```
      it('successful withdraw of funds', async function () {
        const ownerBalanceBefore = await ethers.provider.getBalance(this.owneraddress);                                                                             
        const contractBalanceBefore = await ethers.provider.getBalance(this.erc721a.address);                                                                       
        let overrides = {                                                                                                                                           
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.02").mul(1)            
        };                                                                                                                                                          
        const mintTx = await this.erc721a.connect(this.addr1).mintPublic(1, overrides);                                                                             
        await expect(mintTx)                                                                                                                                        
          .to.emit(this.erc721a, 'Transfer')                                                                                                                        
          .withArgs(ZERO_ADDRESS, this.addr1address, 0);                                                                                                            
        expect(await this.erc721a.ownerOf(0)).to.equal(this.addr1address);                                                                                          
        const contractBalanceAfter = await ethers.provider.getBalance(this.erc721a.address);                                                                        
        expect(contractBalanceAfter).to.equal(contractBalanceBefore.add(ethers.utils.parseEther("0.02")));                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                    
        const withdrawTx = await this.erc721a.connect(this.owner).withdraw();
        
        await ethers.provider.waitForTransaction(withdrawTx.hash);
        const receipt = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(mintTx.hash);
        const feePaid = receipt.cumulativeGasUsed.mul(receipt.effectiveGasPrice);
        const ownerBalanceAfter = await ethers.provider.getBalance(this.owneraddress);

        expect(ownerBalanceAfter).to.equal(ownerBalanceBefore.sub(feePaid).add(contractBalanceAfter));
        
      });
```

Which gets the owners balance before and after the withdrawal of the contracts funds. However the ownerBalanceAfter is always smaller than I expect by a constant amount. I suspect there is something incorrect about how im calculating the gas/fee paid by the transaction but would love some hints as how to fix this.

For clarification its the final expect that is failing with the following.

```
      AssertionError: Expected "9999874362652804411411" to be equal 9999874292985803854075
      + expected - actual
```

Which is the ownerBalance after being smaller by `BigNumber { value: "69667000557336" }`

Comment: Is `this.owneraddress` equal to `this.addr1`? You are not considering the `withdrawTx` fees.

Comment: @ismael thanks for the reply! OMG its a typo. receipt should be from withdrawTX not mintTx.

Cheers mate!